# Do I need a special burner to burn a 3D Blu Ray?

Tags: burning, blu-ray

I was browsing an online shop and found the [Asus BW-12B1ST](http://www.asus.com/Optical_Storage/Internal_Bluray_Drive/BW12B1ST/) burner. Both in the [shopping site's page](http://www.eprice.it/masterizzatori-blu-ray-ASUS/d-4098231) and Asus's website they claim that "with its technology, the Asus burner can burn 3D Blu Rays, convert Blu Rays from 2D to 3D, upscale DVDs...".

Very simple question: is it just to attract buyers, or can't really other dual layer burners burn a 3D Blu Ray?

I mean, suppose I have an ISO of a ~50GB 3D disc. I knew I could burn it with any plain old dual layer BD-burner. I also suppose that 2D->3D conversion and DVD upscaling is done via bundled software, and doesn't require any special hardware rather than a good CPU.

Am I correct?

Comment: If someone mentions "2D to 3D conversion" and "DVD Upscaling" as *features* of their product, I would be **extremely** cautious.

Answer (score 0):

3D blu rays are no more special than regular BD-R.

A normal burner (expect to be able to burn dual-layer 50GB discs) is capable to burn a 3D blu ray. The file system structure is identical to regular discs.